# Using SSH via PHP with different user

Tags: php, shell, ubuntu, ssh, privileges

I have a PHP file in which upon clicking the submit button, another PHP script is being executed. Within the second PHP script a shell script is being executed in which an SSH connection is being done to another server.

The issue I have is that the SSH connection to another server can only be done by a particular user. However the PHP script is being executed by www-data and for such reason I cannot change user, to the user that needs the ssh connection as it requires a password each time.

I also tried to execute the shell script from the first PHP file but still with no success.

My OS is UBUNTU.

Can this be done, and if yes, how can this be achieved?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sudo` command. For passing password to it, there is a `-S` option

Comment: Can you provide more information? I did try using the sudo command but from www-data to the user I am using it still does not work; I was assuming that www-data user is a very limited user.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the option (access and rights etc.) of using private/public keys for SSH? If yes, then your second PHP script would contain something like

```
ssh -l <particular-username> <hostname> -i <private_key_file>
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you logging in? SSH requires a username. Are you providing www-data as that username or the "particular name" as the username?

Comment: I am using another user, not www-data.

Answer (score 0):

If you have or can install sshpass ( http://sourceforge.net/projects/sshpass/ ) you can give that a go, it allows username+password on the commandline, example here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/282319/how-to-use-sshpass